# Closed form or asymptotic expansion for $\int_0^m \frac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

$$\int_0^m \frac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx:n,m \in \mathbb{R}$$
 I'm dubious as to whether there's a closed form for the above, if there is I'll be very happy. Otherwise:

1. Is there a closed form for $$\int_0^\infty \frac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx?$$
2. Is there an asymptotic expansion for $\int_0^m \frac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx$ as $n \to \infty$ with $m$ constant? By this I mean $$\int_0^m \frac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{n^i}{i!}+O(\text{something})$$
   , or something similar.

(Note that the first integral is essentially the integral of the continuous analogue of the Poisson distribution).

Comment: Are you seeking an asymptotic valid when $m \to \infty$?

Comment: Wolfram failed in finding closed forms.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Ideally for all $m$.

Comment: Usually "asymptotic" in this kind of context is referring to a limiting case of a given expression, so I thought you might be interested in one of the cases $m \to \infty$ or $n \to \infty$.  Perhaps you're looking for an approximation instead?

Comment: The sum you mentioned is [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski's_formula) for [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Comment: @AntonioVargas I was referring to asymptotic expansions (as described [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m204/ch2.pdf)), I'll edit the question accordingly. I grant that $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{n^i}{i!}$ may not be the first term of an asymptotic expansion for the integral, it was just an idea.

Comment: Sure, I know what you mean.  But notice that every asymptotic expansion is paired with a statement like "as $x \to 0$" or "as $x \to \infty$".  So in what regime do you want an asymptotic expansion?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Sorry, I meant $n \to \infty$ with constant $m$.

Comment: Have you looked at Euler-Maclaurin summation? The proposed form of the asymptotic expansion is what made me think of it.

Comment: Yes, I thought of it after making my request more precise to Antonio.

Comment: To leading order the asymptotic behavior of the integral is $$\int_0^m \frac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}\,dx = \frac{n^m}{\Gamma(m+1)\log n} + O\left(\frac{n^m}{(\log n)^2}\right)$$ as $n \to \infty$.  The first term in the E-L formula would only predict an asymptotic like $n^{m}$ or $n^{m-1}$, so one should watch for non-negligible contributions from the tail of the E-L series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\int_0^m\dfrac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx$ , by using the formula

[image]

We have $\int_0^m\dfrac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx=m\sum\limits_{s=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{r=1}^{2^s-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{r+1}n^\frac{rm}{2^s}}{2^s\Gamma\left(\dfrac{rm}{2^s}+1\right)}$

For $\int_0^\infty\dfrac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx$ , according to http://books.google.hu/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson%20constant#v=onepage&q=Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson%20constant&f=false,

We have $\int_0^\infty\dfrac{n^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx=e^n-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-ne^y}}{y^2+\pi^2}dy$